# Are there any jQueryMobil image sliders?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been searching around for something similar to [slidesjs](http://slidesjs.com/).com for jQueryMobile, but am unable to find any.

Does anyone here know of a simple image slider for jQueryMobile?

Answer (score 3):

**photoswipe** really cool mobile gallery link: http://www.photoswipe.com/

Comment: Cool, but I'm looking for an image slider that will slide to another image while on the current page.